# Add PEM certificate to Http Request using AngularJS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, https, restangular

I'm currently working on a application that requires getting data from a REST endpoint located in a encrypted network. To access the data in the network I need to either be physically there (currently not possible) or use a PEM certificate provided to me to access the data in the network.

I'm using node as the back-end for my application and AngularJS for the front end.

My HTTPS requests are being done in the front end using **restangular** since I only need to read data from a REST endpoint located at the encrypted network.

tl;dr

My questions is: How can I use a pem certificate to do an HTTPS POST request using angular/restangular? Previously on PHP what I did was invoke curl, but that works different from what I'm discussing above. I used PHP like this a long time ago:

```
function request($endpoint){
    $cert = 'certificate.pem';
    $curl = curl_init();
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_URL            => $endpoint,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERT        => $cert,
        CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD  => $_SESSION['...'] ,
    );
    curl_setopt_array($curl , $options);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do it on the backend because that kind of functionality doesn't really exist on the frontend.

If that backend is node, then you simply use [https.request()](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) and with the `key`, `cert`, and `ca` (or just `pfx`) properties set appropriately.

Comment: Is this the case still or any options came into picture to handle this situation at front-end layer itself ?